# Issue while executing cygwin command from batch file

Tags: bash, batch-file, cygwin

Below is my command. I want to automate this command. so i am using batch file to call this command. But this command is not working in batch file. I can able to change the directory. after from "&&" part i can't able to execute. Please advice

start C:/Cygwin/bin/mintty.exe /bin/env CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash --login -i -c "cd /cygdrive/c/User_login_%date%/ &&   grep "User:" *session* | grep Module | grep -v Administrator | grep -v System | grep -o "User: [A-Za-z]* [A-Za-z]*" | grep -o "[A-Za-z]* [A-Za-z]*$" | sort | uniq -c >> UserLogins.txt;exec bash"

Comment: when i using the command alone its working fine pls help

Answer (score 0):

Is this a directly copy?

```
start C:/Cygwin/bin/mintty.exe /bin/env CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash --login -i -c "cd /cygdrive/c/User_login_%date%/ && grep "User:" session | grep Module | grep -v Administrator | grep -v System | grep -o "User: [A-Za-z]* [A-Za-z]" | grep -o "[A-Za-z] [A-Za-z]*$" | sort | uniq -c >> UserLogins.txt;exec bash"
```

I think you missed a double quote here `"` before `&&`.